# Why do the lanthanides usually use the +3 oxidation state?

Tags: rare-earth-elements

This might seem like a silly question, but why do all of the lanthanides use the +3 oxidation state? I know that some of them can use the +2 (europium, ytterbium) and the +4 (terbium, cerium, praseodymium) but their main oxidation states are +3.

Comment: I would say it is an experimental result !

Comment: It's basically down to ionisation energies, see my answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/53712/16683

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find any other post, but it seems like there are.

Comment: Also see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53605/predominance-of-iii-oxidation-state-for-lanthanides

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87162/europium-stability-in-2-and-3-state/87169