# Lanthanoid Contraction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, atomic-radius

Why is the radius of Europium so unusually high and out of the general trend ? Moreover, at different sources I am getting different values of radii. In some (e.g., Wikipedia) the radii are following the regular trend and in some Europium has been shown to be bigger. (Source : NCERT Class 12 Chemistry Part-1)

[image: NCERT Class 12 Chemistry Part-1]

Comment: What do the other sources say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well spotted! I dare say, the book appears to have used a covalent radius for Europium, while using atomic radii for the other lanthanides.

See "atomic radius" vs "covalent radius" values: for [Europium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium), [Samarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium), and [Gadolinium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadolinium).

Also see [this article](http://www.roaldhoffmann.com/sites/all/files/616.pdf) if you don't like my referencing Wikipedia :P

Comment: For what it's worth, a similar trend is given in Housecroft and Sharpe's *Inorganic Chemistry*, 4th ed. In there, both Eu and Yb have anomalously large "atomic radii" (199 and 194 pm respectively), which could be related to this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53960/why-are-the-densities-of-europium-and-ytterbium-anomalously-low I assume that these radii relate to the interatomic separation in the metal.